# VS 2010 Conditional Configuration

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Good Day,

I am working on an application that displays a splash screen if the application is in Release mode.  It has code that looks like:

```
#if !DEBUG
   applicationScreen.Show();    // Code is greyed out in Debug mode
#endif
```

The problem is I can't step through the code to see the changes I made to the splash screen when I set the application to Release mode:
I've tried the following:

1. Solution Configuration Dropdown - Select Release
2. Build > Configuration Manager > Project > Configuration [Release], Build checked
3. Removed bin/Debug and bin/Release folders and re-compiled the application
4. Closed VS and re-opened again.

EDIT - I *could* comment the conditional directive if I have to.

Is there anything else I'm missing?

TIA,

coson

Comment: So if you put a breakpoint on applicationScreen.Show() and start you application in release mode, you won't stop on the breakpoint? In the project properties (in release mode), is the "Define DEBUG constant" checked? Otherwise, I don't find any explanation. Maybe one last: before your statement, try to put "MessageBox.Show("Test");". If you see the message box, it means that you enter into your statement, but there is an error which is silently handled by the host process. I sometimes have that issue but I still don't known which exact action to carry out (I know it is possible)

Comment: I did check the "Define DEBUG constant" and it was checked off.  The MessageBox.Show("Test") wasn't coming up either.